# error There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

Tags: vb.net

Can you guys help me?

```
Private Sub BtnSimpan_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSimpan.Click
        If BtnSimpan.Text = "&Simpan" Then
            If txtKode.Text = "" Then
                MsgBox("Kode Harus Di isi", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Peringatan")
                txtKode.Focus()
                Exit Sub
            End If
            Call bukaDB()
            CMD = New MySqlCommand("SELECT KodeBarang from tabelbarang WHERE KodeBarang = '" & txtKode.Text & "'", Conn)
            RD = CMD.ExecuteReader()
            RD.Read()
            If RD.HasRows Then
                MsgBox("Maaf, Data dengan Kode tersebut telah ada", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Peringatan")
            Else
                simpan = "INSERT INTO tabelbarang (KodeBarang,NamaBarang,HargaBeli,HargaJual,Stok) VALUES ('" & txtKode.Text & "','" & txtNamaBarang.Text & "','" & txtHargaBeli.Text & "','" & txtHargaJual.Text & "','" & txtStok.Text & "')"
                CMD = New MySqlCommand(simpan, Conn)
                CMD.ExecuteNonQuery() 
                Call isiGrid()
                BtnSimpan.Text = "&Tambah"
                Call Bersih()
            End If
        Else
            BtnSimpan.Text = "&Simpan"
            'Call Bersih()
            txtKode.Enabled = True
            txtNamaBarang.Enabled = True
            txtHargaBeli.Enabled = True
            txtHargaJual.Enabled = True
            txtStok.Enabled = True
            txtKode.Focus()
        End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Yikes, this looks scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues! Also, **no one** uses `Call` anymore. The only purpose for the keyword is preserving compatibility with old code ported forward from the VB6-era.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn For the record, I still use `Call` occasionally, but I don't pretend to conform to "modern" style.

Answer (score 1):

There were several out-dated practices in the code from the question. The code below is updated for modern coding styles, and the mere act of using modern styles will also solve the issue from the question... that is, if you had followed good coding practices from the beginning, this whole class of issue is solved and you would never have had this problem.

This also fixes the **HUGE GAPING SECURITY ISSUE** from the original, which again would have been avoided completely just from keeping up with modern coding standards.

```
Private Sub BtnSimpan_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSimpan.Click

    If BtnSimpan.Text = "&Simpan" AndAlso String.IsNullOrWhitespace(txtKode.Text)  Then
        MsgBox("Kode Harus Di isi", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Peringatan")
        txtKode.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If BtnSimpan.Text <> "&Simpan" Then
        BtnSimpan.Text = "&Simpan"
        'Bersih()
        txtKode.Enabled = True
        txtNamaBarang.Enabled = True
        txtHargaBeli.Enabled = True
        txtHargaJual.Enabled = True
        txtStok.Enabled = True
        txtKode.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Do NOT try to re-use the same connection throughout your application!
    ' It really is more efficient to create a brand new object for most queries,
    '  and only share the connection string.

    'Also, JUST DO THE INSERT.
    'Make sure there is a unique constraint on the KodeBarang column,
    ' and handle the exception if it fails.

    ' Correct for *either one* of the above issues, and the
    ' problem in the question never would have happened.
 
    Try
        Using CN As New MySqlConnection("Connection string here"), _
              CMD As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tabelbarang (KodeBarang,NamaBarang,HargaBeli,HargaJual,Stok) VALUES (@KodeBarang, @NamaBarang, @HargaBeli, @HargaJual, @Stok)", CN)

            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KodeBarang", txtKode.Text)
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NamaBarang", txtNamaBarang.Text)
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HargaBeli", txtHargaBeli.Text)
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HargaJual", txtHargaJual.Text)
            CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Stok", txtStok.Text)   

            CN.Open()
            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery() 
        End Using

        isiGrid()
        BtnSimpan.Text = "&Tambah"
    Catch ex As MySqlException When ex.Code = 1062 '1062 is Duplicate Key Violation
        MsgBox("Maaf, Data dengan Kode tersebut telah ada", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Peringatan")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) :)

Comment: @Jimi It turns out the MySql connector handles inference differently, and so it's safe(r) for that DB.

Comment: I assume you refer to this [Start Using AddWithValue](https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/). Still kind of *weird* in a post of yours (that's why there's a little smile).

Comment: @Jimi That's one place I've seen. There are a couple others explaining why MySql is mostly immune. And yes, generally I still prefer to be explicit in my database types, but I felt like I was throwing enough at the poor soul already :)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I have been using MySql.Data.MySqlClient. I believe the only article I can find for this is https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/ refers to a different library, MySqlConnector. Is the idea the same for the library I am using?

Comment: @Mary I believe so, as it's not so much about the library as it is the underlying native format used to communicate with the MySql service.